# Two related queries needs to be one

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know this is a basic thing but SQL is a serious weak point of mine...

I have the following query ("query1")

```
select 
    SC.statues, SC_some_real_code 
from 
    [corpdb_gs].[dbo].[Simple_Codes] SC
inner join
    [corpdb_gs].[dbo].[real_simple_essentials] RSE
on 
    SC.statues = RSE.se_statutes 
AND 
    SC.some_real_code = RSE.se_statutes_reason
```

I need to return only the rows in table `[db2].[dbo].[statusYo]` where

```
    statusYo.code = "query1".SC.statues 
AND 
    statusYo.reason = "query1".SC.some_real_code
```

Help?

Comment: You mention two queries in the title and there is only one query in the post? Where is the other query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select * from [db2].[dbo].[statusYo] query2
    inner join 
   (select 
        SC.statues as statues , SC.some_real_code as some_real_code   
    from 
        [corpdb_gs].[dbo].[Simple_Codes] SC
    inner join
        [corpdb_gs].[dbo].[real_simple_essentials] RSE
    on 
        SC.statues = RSE.se_statutes 
    AND 
        SC.some_real_code = RSE.se_statutes_reason) query1  
on query1.statues =query2.code 
and query1.some_real_code=query2.reason
```

this will work for you......

Comment: This is close. I ended up figuring it out literally 2 minutes ago and came back... The [Select * from...] needs a FROM and then the INNER JOIN. At least it does for me but this is otherwise identical to what I came up with. Thanks!